# How find /i "String" on PsExec output on cmd

Tags: cmd, find, psexec

I want to run a remote command using PsExec.exe and analize the output to know if it was successful:

```
PsExec.exe -i -s -d \\60.60.43.3 -u MYDOMAIN\User -p 12345678 calc.exe | find /i "ID"

If %errorlevel% equ 0 echo OK
If %errorlevel% equ 1 echo NO

Pause
```

I always get "NO" as output. Eventhough I can see that the output has "ID" in it and the PsExec command was successfu.

What is the proper way to validate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PsExec returns the ID on error output stream (2), merge the error stream with normal output `2>&1`.

```
PsExec.exe -i -s -d \\60.60.43.3 -u MYDOMAIN\User -p 12345678 calc.exe 2>&1| find /i "ID"
If %errorlevel% equ 0 echo OK
If %errorlevel% equ 1 echo NO
Pause
```